# How can I make the menubar in PyQt5 have initial focus?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have created a GUI with a menubar. However, when I run the app and the window opens I want to be able to iterate through the buttons using only the keyboard. This works for the buttons and lineedit fields, but does not work for the MenuBar. 
How can I be able to get focus on the MenuBar such that I can iterate through the actions in the menubar using only the keyboard?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ConfigNumbers(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi                         (   self)
        self.setWindowTitle                  (  'Nr configs'                    )

    def setupUi(self, ConfigNumbers):
        ConfigNumbers.setEnabled             (   True                               )
        ConfigNumbers.setFocusPolicy         (   QtCore.Qt.TabFocus                 )

        layout                                     = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        #ELEMENTS
        #ACTIONS TO MENUBAR
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        delete = self.menuBar.addMenu("Delete")
        add    = self.menuBar.addMenu("Add")

        deleteNr = []
        addNr    = QtWidgets.QAction("Add New Master", self)
        addNr.setShortcut("Ctrl+A")
        # addNr.triggered.connect(lambda: self.addNewNr())
        add.addAction(addNr)
        for nr in range (1,5):
            deleteNr.append(QtWidgets.QAction("Nr %d" % nr, self))
            delete.addAction(deleteNr[nr-1])
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.menuBar.setFocus)
        layout.addWidget(self.menuBar)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("push"))
        self.setLayout( layout )

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ConfigNumbers()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have tried:
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.menuBar.setFocus)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to focus the menu to be able to select it with the keyboard, you can select it by using the key `Alt` which is the standard key to achieve this, furthermore, you can add the ampersand character before a letter to your menu action titles and then you can use the combination of `Alt+letter` to access a menu, for example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ConfigNumbers(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi                         (   self)
        self.setWindowTitle                  (  'Nr configs'                    )

    def setupUi(self, ConfigNumbers):
        ConfigNumbers.setEnabled             (   True                               )
        ConfigNumbers.setFocusPolicy         (   QtCore.Qt.TabFocus                 )

        layout                                     = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        #ELEMENTS
        #ACTIONS TO MENUBAR
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

        delete = self.menuBar.addMenu("Dele&te")
        add    = self.menuBar.addMenu("&Add")

        deleteNr = []
        addNr    = QtWidgets.QAction("Add New &Master", self)
        addNr.setShortcut("Ctrl+A")
        # addNr.triggered.connect(lambda: self.addNewNr())
        add.addAction(addNr)
        for nr in range (1,5):
            deleteNr.append(QtWidgets.QAction("Nr %d" % nr, self))
            delete.addAction(deleteNr[nr-1])
        layout.addWidget(self.menuBar)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("push"))
        self.setLayout( layout )

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ConfigNumbers()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now when I hit and release the key `Alt` I can see the following:

[image: PyQt focus on menu]

Now you can use the arrow keys to move through the menus; If I hit `Alt+A` it opens the "Add" menu and so on...

You should also avoid focusing on items using a timer as it may interact with user actions in the interface.